# remove text on tab product description wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

[image: This picture]

how to remove that please help
i have tried remove with css using display:none;
any Specific css to remove only

this text ? 
take a look at the best free wordpress themes 2017

Comment: Its look like you are using an illegal theme? Better buy original theme on Themeforest or your website will unsecure with hacker because many many backdoor usually included on 'null theme'

Comment: Is this a free theme or nulled ?

Comment: no im using premium template using original license

Comment: i buy it from theme envantomarket

Comment: If you sure all your themes and plugins are download from safe source like Themeforest or WordPress.org, better open a ticket to supporter of Flatsome theme at https://themeforest.net/item/flatsome-multipurpose-responsive-woocommerce-theme/5484319/support